# Normal space is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I know that a compact Hausdorff space implies Normal, but does the converse holds?

I.e. If a space is normal, it is compact and Haudorff. (Although $T_4$ imlicitly implies $T_2$)

Comment: No. Every metric space is normal, and there are metric spaces that aren't even *locally* compact.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{Q}$ for example, with the usual topology from $\mathbb{R}$. This space is normal (it is metrizable), but it is not compact (and in fact, it is not even locally compact, as @Mike Miller hinted).